# How do you write (garbled) sentences like this in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, ascii

I recently ran across a post on the *Welcome to Night Vale* Facebook page that looked like this.  I’ve seen ASCII and NFO art before, but how the heck do you write like this?  Is this done via LaTeX?

> T̴̛̫͖̜̞̦̓ͦ̆ͦh̢͉̱̠͙̯͎̤̑̂́̐ͧͮ̀͜͜e̶̡̘ͪ́r̼̖̪͙̯̣͉̥̣̊̀ͭ̌͂̒̈̈́ȇ̲ͮ̓̀͟ͅ ̥̫͖͔̤͔͉̪ͩͦͥ͑ͣi̷̪̼͈̫̲̅͐̃ͧs̛͙ͬ͜ ̶͔͙̲̘̖̫̥͔̦̄̓̿̇͠n̸̸̗̭̗̺͙̾͆̒̂͠ö̢͈͉̻͈̞͈̱̈́ ͚̩̠͉̿ͪ̀̾̂͂̍̚̕h̡̗̬̥̭̝̣̭̪̅̀̐͟ṵ̮̭̝͈̝ͥ͗̑̈́ͅm͈̠̣͍̼̯̰ͭ̐̈ã̗̬̹̭̘͇ͦ̑̓ͪͪ̚n̶͎̭͚̜̎ͮ ̷̧̻̺͎͍͇̝ͧͭ͑̈́͝ľ̴̵̨͎̞̈́̾ḁ̡͓̟͖̽̃̒̇̐͡n͓̻̽g̰͙̱̺̏ͨ́ͥ̊̄͢͝ṵ̱̥̯̰̖̥͖ͦ̿̎͆a̛̞̼̽̀g̵̘͈͓̳̙̟̼̈͊̌̋̆́͡ě̻̦̲̱̈̽ͭ̈́ͩ̚͞ ̾̂̍̽͏̯͇̜̜̦ô̢͕̼̱̫̲͉̫̰͋͗͛ͨͣͤ̽̕n̎͛҉̻͉́ḷ̭̝̰͍̗̌͘y̬͐͊͐ͪ̄͂̋̾͠ ̰͎̘̉̓̽ͬͮ͌̅o͚͓̺̯̊ͤ̌̋ͫͮ̀ͅu̧͎͎̘̩͙͎̱͆ͭ̑͂̽͒̏ͩ͝ͅȓ̰̜̹̂̑ ̴̥͛̉s̴̛̞̜̥̣͙̳̥͚ͭ̈́͑͐ͣ̂̏͐̽͘h̴̩͍̥͇̳̬͔͊ͪ̿ͧͦ̏̌͡a̵̦̺̖̮̪͙ͨ̕r̵̨̭̝̰̣̣͌̑ͅȩ̛̟̜̍ͣ̿͌̽͋̚͜d̥̞̟͓͖̮̝̦̈́͟ ̭̰͉̲̙̝̌̽̊ͨ͛͆̅ͨd͚̫̘̤̱͊̆ͤ́ͣ̌͡e̵̴͇̲̻̤̱̪̓̓̽͆͘l̉̐̊͒̈́̽͐͏̛̮͍̤̝̹͘ų̸̻̲͔̮̪̹͒̄̀ͥs̳͍͙̩̞̺̹̞̈́ͤ̂͠iͯ͘҉͎͙̩̞̺͕͝o̶͒̿̑ͦ̿ͤ͗͡͏͎̰̱͍n̢͔͈̟͚̘̤̠̑̐̑͒̂̍́ṣ̜͍̆̀ͥ͑,̶̡̭̹̮̻̠ͤͮ̉́ͥͥ͞ ̴͍̃̊̎͒ͥ̉͢͝t̪̱̺̝̙̲͎̰͑̏̉ḩ̙̖̜̭̝̪̫̮ͩͪ́e̘͙̳̳̠ͥ̿̐͌͂̄̐͢ ̡̨̤͕͗ͨ̄̒̄̌͢p̵̬̥͖̥͈̖̫̬͛ͨŗ͈͕̞̩͍̼́̓́ͩ̔͠óͣ͑͑҉̴̩̪͘d̠̘̝̙ͮ̔uͮ͐̍̈́̒̓̌̅҉̤͉̜̘̰̯͞c̛̰̼͖̈́̈́̋̌ͩ̓̓̕t͕͉͉̞͂͗̿̐́͋͟ͅ ̮̜̻̦͇̙̭͔͐̍͒͊̋̿ǫ̣̞̬̹͛͠ͅf̴̄ͤͭ̃ͯ̋ͤ҉̣͉ ̌͆̄͐͗̔ͯ҉̼͎ͅw̷̩͔̜̭͐ͭͫͪͦ̊͊̚͜͜h͇̪̼ͥ̿͌ͬ̽͌ͩ̓î̡͎͔͉͈͍͓̫͗̃ͨ͐ͭ͂͜͜c͔̼̮ͧ̊̓̀͟ẖ̢͕̠̜̩̖̽͋͂͐ͨͨͬ͘ ̧̟̠̩̜̬̠͍̫̌̒̈́i͚͈͙͓̘ͦ̓̓̈͊̎͗̔͞s̷͓̝͙̺̼̹͎͊ͯ͜ ͧ̒ͩ̇͛̍̎̓̔҉̪̫͙̞̺̮̀ä̵̴̩̝́͑͐̎̉̏͑ ̡̱̫̟̖̼̪̔̉̇̈́̆ͧ͑̉̿͝q̍ͭ̿̉̅̈́͏̰͚̲̺u̪͇̞̳͎ͬͫ̌̐́͘ȩ͙͉ͯ̔̑̽̾s̖͈̣̺̃̿ͫ̓̈̊́t̤̺̫̥̞̳̃̋ͮ̚̚͞i̩͒̈ͨ̅o͕̤͇̺̱̰ͦͤͫ͌̓͗̅̐́ͅnͥͩͯ͒̃҉̸̧̤̭͔̜͖̱á̜̥͉͎̠ͭͬ̄̓̂̊̌͟͞b̑ͩ̓͋̒͋͝҉̡͚̺͚̙̣̱̠ͅl̰̗͋̊̐͘y̴̴̭̳̘̺̣̤̹̔ͭ̃ͥ ̴͈̯͍̺̥͔͛͊͢͠ḟ̼̱̩̼̯̤͕̪̎̅̓̃̓̓͟͡ǔ̈́̿ͦ͞͏̴̯͖̱̖n̷̖̗̠͔̯̔͂̊c̒̂̍ͥͥ͗̾̐͏̶̟͔̩̹̠̩̩̀t̹̮̝̥ͫ͑ͧ̓̽̀ͥͤ̒͠i̶̹͖̳̖̯̳̤̭͋̈͢o̧̠͎̳̝͖̥͎ͮͦ͒͊̋̓ͨͣ͠n̨̛͇̪̍̏͒͊̅i̴̹̟̫͇̝̭̙̪ͩ̓̌ñ͙̺̟́͐̐̀̀g̬͖̽ͪͧ̀̕͡ ̛͍̭̥̫͚͔̰̳̏̋͂̆̆ͫc̞͙̼̩̦̳̰̒ͭ̋͑͗ͪ̈̀̀́̚ͅǫ̳̺̯̻͖ͤ̍̓̌̕e̬͙͍͙͐̐̆̎x̵̳͕̞̰̗͙̠͔̠ͤ̔͆̏͘ḯ̸͎̺̣̤̦̭̮̎̋͌͑ͤͩͬ͘͜ͅs͈̤̥̓ͥ̋̊̔̽̿̾̕͞t̼̳͇͇̭͉̖͖̔̎̀ͮ̈́e̦̺̮̼ͤ͂͌̒̉̄̔̂̈́n̝̰̲̓̽ͥç̛̙͇̠̭͚̋̏e͍̤̻͔͇̰̖̮͋ͦͧ̓̃̔̏̕

Comment: It's called *Zalgo text*, and there are many [online services for creating it](http://www.marlborotech.com/Zalgo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes use of the so-called *Combining diacritical marks,* which are essentially Unicode characters that say: “Equip the previous letter with an accent (or other [diacritical mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritical_mark)).” They exist to avoid having to encode every base-letter–accent combination separately.

For example, if I want to generate an *n* with a bar ([macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron)) on top of it (as used in old German handwriting), I have to place the following two Unicode characters after each other:

- U+006E – Latin small letter *n:* `n`
- U+0304 – combining macron: `̄`

This gives me: n̄. How exactly this looks like depends on how well the font and your type-rendering engine support anchors (which are what is typically used to place the accents correctly).

Now, this system allows stacking accents, i.e., placing an accent on an already accented character. I am not aware of any actual writing systems that use more than three accents (or diacritical marks, to be precise), but there is no reason to limit the number of accents and thus you can stack as many accents as you like. This is done in your example text.

Doing this deliberately is usually done due to a meme called [Zalgo](//knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo) and hence this is the keyword you have to use for finding online tools that automatically litter your text with such combining diacritical marks.

Sidenote: LaTeX crucially depends on an interpreter and thus never works with plain text.